# Create user/password Redis V5

Tags: authentication, redis, passwords, user-accounts

I need to create a new user on REDIS V5 and assign a password.
This is for application connect.

I only have the requirepass on redis.conf. But this password is only for me and i don't share it.

I don't have ACL.

Thanks
Regards.
Hernán.

I'm expecting a new user for the applications connect

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: NO, you cannot do that with Redis 5. You need to upgrade to Redis 6, and use the ACL feature.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not provided with what access you want the user to be created, here is a sample command that will create a user "`myuser`" with a password of "`mypassword`" which will have access to all commands except the commands that are tagged as "`dangerous`"

```
acl setuser myuser on >mypassword +@all -@dangerous ~*
```

When you run this command in redis-cli, this user gets created and it's information is stored in memory, so you will want to persist this data in a file so that it doesn't get lost when redis is restarted. You can do so by running:

```
ACL SAVE
```